# meaning of ことなんてない

Tags: words

Some context (this is from a Doraemon episode):

> 2人の人間の間でこのスイッチを押すとそのあとの人生のコースが入れ替わる。
>
> でも言っとくけど…　人の人生のコースを進んでもいいことなんてないよ

So, this is something like:

> If you press this switch between two people, their life paths will be exchanged.
>
> But, for your information... It's not that (?) you may continue the life path of a person (?)

I don't understand the "ことなんてない" bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「～～なんて」＝「～～なんか」.

It is used to **make light of a thing (~~)**.

> = "a thing like ~~", "something/anything such as ~~"

Thus,

> 「いいことなんてない」 means:
>
> "there is nothing good (whatsoever)"

「人{ひと}」 does ***not*** mean a "person" in this context.  **It means "another person" or "others"**.  This is a very common mistake among Japanese-learners.

> "There wouldn't be anything good (whatsoever) if you lived the life of another person."