# Meaning of 何も with なんてない sentence end

Tags: grammar, translation

I need some help with translating the following sentence, to make sure that I understand all the nuisances with it and am translating accordingly.

それなら何もとまどう必要なんてない。
If so there’s no need to worry about nothing/anything.

The 何も part can either mean 'nothing' or 'anything' depending on the negation according to Jisho.org. The sentence ends with なんて which means 'to make light of something' according to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54808/meaning-of-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84). Does the ない form ending means that 何も is translatable as 'nothing', or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It can be either なにも{LHH} (0), which is combination of interrogative noun 何 and particle も, or adverb なにも{HLL} (1).

If it's the former, the sentence means "There’s no need to hesitate about anything".

The latter, "You don't need to go so far as being at a loss".

Answer (score 0):

'〇〇必要なんてない' implies the other person thinks 〇〇 is necessary, so the speaker is saying that there's no such thing as '〇〇' being necessary.

> 何もとまどう必要なんてない

There's no reason at all be bewildered.